# std::cout doen't like std::endl and string in conditional-if

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, cout, stdstring

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void PrintVector(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, bool)’:
main.cpp:16:41: error: overloaded function with no contextual type information
  std::cout << ((newline)? (std::endl) : "");
                                         ^~
```

Why std::cout doen't like std::endl and string in conditional-if?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: The ternary operator requires result values of the same type.

Comment: There is also no performance reason to use the ternary operator here. The difference between `?:` and an if-else-statement, if any, will be shadowed by the cost of the I/O operation.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you don't need those parentheses around `newline` and `std::endl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to:

```
std::cout << (newline? "\n" : "") << std::flush;
```

It is not possible to write it with ' (would be faster):

```
std::cout << (newline? '\n' : '') << std::flush;
```

because '' is empty and leads to "error: empty character constant".

The solution with the conditional-if is so complex that one should prefer the following:

```
if (newline) std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::endl` is a stream manipulator. It's a function. It does not have a common type with `""`. So they cannot be the two types of a conditional expression. Since the common type is the type of the whole expression.

You probably don't even need everything `std::endl` does besides adding a new line, so just replace it with `"\n"` to print a new-line. That way the common type may be deduced to `const char*` after all the usual conversions are performed on the operands.